# Matplotlib - How to plot lines of minimum and maximum gradient through error bars?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

My code:

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit import Model

def bestfit(x, m, c):
    return m * x + c

x = [2.8672E-02, 2.2199E-02, 1.8180E-02, 1.5410E-02, 1.3325E-02]
y = [8.64622E-03, 7.07473E-03, 6.13109E-03, 5.46607E-03, 4.90341E-03]
xerror =[8.2209E-07, 4.9280E-07, 3.3052E-07, 2.3748E-07, 1.7756E-07]
yerror = [1.62083E-04, 1.45726E-04, 1.38127E-04, 1.26587E-04, 1.22042E-04]

mod = Model(bestfit)
params = mod.make_params(m = 0.2421, c = 0.0017)
result = mod.fit(y, params, x = x)
print(result.fit_report())
print(1 - result.residual.var() / np.var(y))

matplotlib.rcParams['font.serif'] = "Times New Roman"
matplotlib.rcParams['font.family'] = "serif"
plt.plot(x, y, 'bo', markersize = 1.5)
plt.plot(x, result.best_fit, color = 'red', linewidth = 0.5)
plt.xlabel(r'Inverse Mass $g^{-1}$')
plt.ylabel('Damping Coefficient $s^{-1}$')


plt.errorbar(x, y, xerror, yerror)
plt.show()
```

I'm hoping to create lines of minimum and maximum gradient, along with their equations like so:

[image]

I was able to do it in Excel, but that required manual input of the 4 extreme data points.

How do I do this automatically?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what the curves the other program is showing.  It sort of looks like it may be just drawing a line through the points

```
  (x[0], y[0]-yerror[0]), (x[-1], y[-1]+yerror[-1])
  (x[0], y[0]+yerror[0]), (x[-1], y[-1]-yerror[-1])
```

That should be easy for you to plot with matplotlib.  But that doesn't seem particularly meaningful to me.

On the other hand, if you want to include in your plot some measure of the uncertainty in the result of the fit, then there are a couple of options. First, you could evaluate the model using values for the parameters that are taken from the best_fit values and the uncertainties in those values.  For example, you might do (once you have `result`):

```
pars = result.params

curve1 = bestfit(x, pars['m'].value+pars['m'].stderr, pars['c'].value)
curve2 = bestfit(x, pars['m'].value-pars['m'].stderr, pars['c'].value)
curve3 = bestfit(x, pars['m'].value, pars['c'].value+pars['c'].stderr)
curve4 = bestfit(x, pars['m'].value, pars['c'].value-pars['c'].stderr)
curve5 = bestfit(x, pars['m'].value+pars['m'].stderr, pars['c'].value+pars['c'].stderr)
curve6 = bestfit(x, pars['m'].value+pars['m'].stderr, pars['c'].value-pars['c'].stderr)
curve7 = bestfit(x, pars['m'].value-pars['m'].stderr, pars['c'].value+pars['c'].stderr)
curve8 = bestfit(x, pars['m'].value-pars['m'].stderr, pars['c'].value-pars['c'].stderr)
```

and then plot some of those.

A simpler and possibly more informative plot to make would be to use the `eval_uncertainties` method of the `ModelResult`.  See 
https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/model.html#calculating-uncertainties-in-the-model-function  A simple use would be:

```
dely = result.eval_uncertainty()
plt.fill_between(x, result.best_fit-dely, result.best_fit+dely, color="#ABABAB")
```

Also, since you have uncertainties in `y`, you can use these in the fit itself.   To do this with `lmfit.Model`, you would pass in `1.0/yerror` as a `weight` to the `fit` method:

```
result = mod.fit(y, params, x=x, weights=1.0/np.array(yerror))
```

(note: the data and uncertainties should really be numpy arrays, not lists).  I think for your data (where the uncertainties are similar in size) it will not make much of a difference to the best fit values and uncertainties, but it will make a difference in the reported statistics such as chi-square.

Finally, for a simple linear model (that is, a model that is linear in the parameters, like this one is), you don't really need to use an iterative approach like `lmfit.Model` but could use linear regression methods.